# What is the proper way to set up resource URLs in a ClojureScript single page application

Tags: url, clojure, single-page-application, clojurescript

I am developing a Clojure/ClojureScript SPA based on http-kit, compojure and tiny bits of hiccup on backend and mainly reagent on frontend. Project is done with leiningen, based on hand-wrecked chestnut template.

When I tried to make more complex URLs than just "/" the following setup created a mess for me:

- When producing the initial hiccup to serve HTML and adding includes for CSS and JS files I followed the examples and added them as relative urls like

  ```
  (include-css "css/style.css")
  ;and
  (include-js "js/compiled/out/goog/base.js")
  (include-js "js/compiled/myproject.js")
  ```

  (note absence of slash in the beginning)
- In the chestnut template I got default :asset-path option for cljsbuild set to `"js/compiled/out"`

Of course, when I tried to add a route to the same page with the http://my-domain/something URL in addition to root http://my-domain/ and load it, the thing failed to get any of my assets (trying to fetch them under e.g. `/something/js/compiled/myproject.js`).

I was able to fix this issue for explicitly included assets by making those urls relative to root (prepending a slash to each of them). It left me with the same problem with the script tag with `src="js/compiled/out/cljs_deps.js"` injected by cljsbuild, but this one I fixed by making :asset-path relative to root as well.

It all seems to work properly now, but the fact that I had to make some head-scratching and a surprisingly large amount of googling to finally resolve this makes me feel this is not the default approach. Hence the questions:

1. Did I do the right thing by converting all asset urls to relative-to-root ones? (Keeping in mind that I'm working on an SPA)
2. If yes, why isn't this a default approach and why I keep seeing relative-to-current location URLs everywhere (including all the examples on the web as well as lein templates)?

**Update:**
The relevant part of my app's compojure routes looks like this:

```
(defroutes home-routes

  (resources "/")

  (GET "/" _
       (friend/authenticated
        (html-response
         (app-page))))
  (GET "/something*" _
       (friend/authenticated
        (html-response
         (app-page)))))
```

Comment: What do you set as resource path with compojure's `resource`?

Comment: @schaueho it's (resources "/") - I added the routes definition to the question body

Comment: You might need to put `resources` at the bottom of your routes?

Comment: @DanielCompton it didn't occur to me, but do you think it will be able to process /something/js/compiled/myproject.js correctly afterwards? Also, what about 404 handler then - shouldn't it be the last one?

Comment: Usually you see app routes, then resources, then 404 at the end. I don't have a ring web app handy to test it out though sorry.

Comment: @DanielCompton, thank you anyway! It will be easy for me to test that on my side.